# How to copy first and last row of each table of Word file to an Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

There are around 150 tables in my Word file. Each table has six rows and two columns.

I need to copy the first and last row values from each table to an Excel sheet.

The first row will have my table id and last row data is Pass/Fail.

Comment: Priyanka, does my solution below work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should try to post the code that you tried so far so we can help you debug and get to the final answer:

1. Summarize the problem
2. Describe what you’ve tried
3. Show some code
   When appropriate, share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem (also called a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

But, I'll try to give you some code to get going.

If it helps you, please consider to mark it as the correct answer :)

Please try the following code:

```
Sub extract_word_table_values_to_excel()

    Dim word_app As Object, temp_doc As Object, word_doc As Object

    'Set word_app = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    ActiveSheet.Calculate

    word_path = Range("Word_path")
    'Place your word doc path here in the named range on the sheet

    temp = Split(word_path, "\")
    word_name = temp(UBound(temp))

    Set word_doc = GetObject(word_path)
    Set word_app = word_doc.Application

    word_app.Visible = True
    word_doc.Activate

    excel_row = 1

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim word_table As Word.Table 'Or As variant

    For Each word_table In word_doc.Tables
        Err.Clear
        For i = 1 To word_table.Rows.Count Step word_table.Rows.Count - 1
            'Step count minus 1 means only first and last row are looped
            For j = 1 To word_table.Columns.Count
                part = word_table.Rows(i).Cells(j).Range.Text
                part = Left(part, Len(part) - 1)
                part = Replace(part, vbNewLine, "")
                'MsgBox part
                Sheet2.Cells(excel_row, j).Value = part
            Next j
            excel_row = excel_row + 1
        Next i
        excel_row = excel_row + 1 'Leave row between tables
    Next word_table

    MsgBox "done"

    word_doc.Save
    'word_app.Quit
    Set word_doc = Nothing
    Set word_app = Nothing       

End Sub
```

Please leave a comment if you have a question.